# How to create a function that can format real numbers to currency string using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I need to create a function that can format real numbers to currency in the following format:

1. It should include a leading currency character such as **$**
2. comma separators for thousands
3. rounding to a defined number of decimal places
4. padding with leading and trailing zeros

Comment: You could use the already existing `ToString` method with a [Custom Numeric Format String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(Convert(12345678))
    End Sub

    Function Convert(number) As String

        Dim str as String = ""

        While number > 0

            str = (number MOD 1000).ToString() + str
            number = number \ 1000

            If number > 0

                str = "," + str

            End If

        End While

        Return "$" + str

    End Function

End Module
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/EYJvMC

Comment: @tim I'll take a look at vb.net and rewrite it

Comment: @tim Okay, I fixed it as well as added a dotnetfiddle link. If this helped, please mark it as accepted by pressing the checkmark next to the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.IO

Public Module Module1

    Dim value, result As Decimal

    Public Sub main()
        result = convert()
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Function convert()

        Console.Write("Enter value: ")
        value = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("$" & value.ToString("#,###,###.00"))
        Return value

    End Function

End Module
```